# Hard drives only showing half their capacity - no unallocated space - had been used in Windows pool ("raid")

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, raid, storage-spaces

I sincerely hope someone has any kind of idea, I have been trying for days to solve this problem.

I have 4x 16 TB Toshiba hard drives running in my Windows 10 PC and plugged in directly over the internal SATA ports of my Asus X570 Prime-pro motherboard (no LSI or HBA). I had them running in a Pool in Windows storage spaces (raid 10) and deleted the storage space a few days ago.
The drives are only one year old and enterprise grade, so there shouldn't be any problems with the drives themselves.

Now each drive shows up in the Windows partition manager as roughly 7,4 TB, so half of what the usable space should roughly be.
There is no unallocated space, I have formatted the drives at least twice. I have tried a program which wipes the drive by writing zeros onto it.
I did try `diskpart`and to `clean` the drives and I tried to `expand` the volumes (I have tried `expand filesystem`and `expand volume` ) - to no avail.

I have tried to make a partition and then make said partition smaller in the hopes it would load the rest of the space. Also have I tried to assign a new Letter to a partition (have read that tip somewhere)

Next I have tried to plug them into another SATA port. I have also tried a recovery programm to try and find lost partitions.

CrystalDisk info does not showing aynthing out of the ordinary either - all the drives are at full health.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xC6a.jpg)

I seemingly to not understand enough about hard drives, but isn`t there a way to completely restore them to factory settings - to wipe them clean of everything, wipe the MBR, restore the firmware - I simply do not know.

I have also read something about DCO (Device Configuration Overlay) and Host protected area - might this be a clue?

I hope that someone more knowledgeable can hint me towards any kind of solution, as I simply am not even finding anymore solutions I could try.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the exact model number of the disk drives?

Comment: Windows 10 can only handle limited disk sizes with MBR. Format them with GPT (GUID Partition Table)

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I am a moron - the simple solution seemingly is, that I have been scammed and received 8 TB drives instead of 16 TB ones...  the model number is TOSHIBA MG06ACA800E and after googleing it, it shows as 8 TB drives.The easiest solutions are often the hardest ones to find, gosh damn it.

Comment: The drives are actually formatted with GPT - I guess I somehow mixed it up when writing the question, sorry.